# Using Regex in vue router path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In Vue router, I have a path `/[can be anything in here]/products/shoes/nike`

The first part is languageCode that can be anything or it may not be exist at all. I want to cover all of the possibilities. I tried

```
  {
    path: ':lang/products/shoes/nike',
    meta: { allowGuest: true },
    redirect: { name: 'shoes' },
  },
```

Tried with `path: '/:catchAll(.*)/products/shoes/nike'` too but didn't work either.

I am still not able to catch routes starting with a languageCode. Is there a way I can do it with regex?

Comment: What does the console returns whe you try `path: '/:lang/products/shoes/nike'`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `:lang` optional in your route's path, you need to use `?` modifier.
So, update your route object as follows:

```
{
    path: '/:lang?/products/shoes/nike',
    meta: { allowGuest: true },
    redirect: { name: 'shoes' },
}
```

Refer official vue-router docs for detailed info- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#optional-parameters